# Alternative to Thread.Sleep that block

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am looking for an alternative to calling Thread.Sleep which does not block the thread but instead returns the thread back into the thread pool.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
await Task.Delay(delay);
```

Comment: I put this in and made the method in which this line appears async.  Do I do anything in the calling method?

Comment: Nothing, That's what will call the method and "waits asynchronously", If you need calling method also needs to wait, then use await there also..

Comment: @SachinKainth note that any non-`async` code will keep running on the primary thread; you basically need to convert all the impacted code to `async`/`await` for this to behave without changing the order of execution. For example if your code calls `SomeMethodAsync()` but **doesn't** `await` the result, then the code after that method-call may be executed even though the `SomeMethodAsync()` has barely started

Answer (score 1):

If the thread is returning to the pool, then it isn't going to do any more work in the method in question. Make the next bit of the method a separate method, and create a Timer that calls it.

Comment: Or `Task.Delay`. I feel like an old dog that forgot the new trick now, after seeing Sriram's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also a Timer for example:

```
using System.Timers;

private void Main()
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 5000; // 5 seconds
    t.AutoReset = false;
    t.Elapsed += new SleepDone(TimerElapsed);
    t.Start();
}

private void SleepDone(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("HERE WHAT COME AFTER SLEEP");
}
```

Comment: Why `AutoReset = true` ?

Comment: Thanks @SriramSakthivel +1 for the good tip. He need to run the delay one time.